# Blank pages using the SLIM PHP framework

Tags: php, apache2, slim

I am currently developing a web application using the latest Slim version. Everything works perfectly on my professional computer (running on Ubuntu 12.04) but I would like to work on the project at home during my holidays. Thus, I have copied the project on my personal computer (running on mac os x 10.6.8). The problem is I always get blank pages. It does not look to be a rewrite problem since even with the ugly address, it does not work.

Please find below files and information that might be useful to fix the issue.

Folder structure (/Users/Yoann/Sites/DS)

```
-.htaccess 
- index.php
- vendor/
- utils/
- services/
```

The utils and services directories contain some php classes and are not of interest to fix my issue.

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [QSA,L]
```

index.php (sample)

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
function autoload_class_multiple_directory($class_name) 
{
    # List all the class directories in the array.
    $array_paths = array(
        'utils/', 
        'services/'
    );

    foreach($array_paths as $path)
    {
        $file = sprintf('./%s%s.class.php',  $path, strtolower($class_name));
        if(is_file($file)) 
        {         
            include_once $file;
        } 
    }
}

spl_autoload_register('autoload_class_multiple_directory');

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');

$app = new \Slim\Slim(array(
    "MODE" => "debug"
));

/* **********************************
 *          ROUTE DEFINITIONS
 * **********************************/
$arrDs = array("generator" => new Generator(),
               "average" => new Average()
               );

$app->get('/', function () use ($app,$arrDs){
    echo "dans la fonction de base !!! <br/>";
    foreach ($arrDs as $name => $obj){
        echo $name ."<br/>";
    }
});

$app->run();
?>
```

I am using a virtual host defined as

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin [email blocked]
DocumentRoot "/Users/Yoann/Sites/DS"
ServerName ds.local
ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/ds-error_log" 
CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/ds-access_log" combined


  <Directory "/Users/Yoann/Sites/DS">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

In development environment always set error_reporting to E_ALL and display_errors to true.

```
php.ini:
display_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

You'll see all errors, warnings, etc ...

Comment: I forgot to mention it but these two lines were already in my php.ini file. The point is I do not have any error/debug/info message...

Comment: Make sure "apache" or whatever user runs the webserver has write access to the logs you mention in the vhost. `sudo su www-data; touch .....ds-access_log` for example. Else just leave out the custom log locations and have apache report to the default logs.